# Dynamic typeahead in Adaptive Card Task flow

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm trying to implement the dynamic typeahead search as was shown on the below resources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/dynamic-search?tabs=desktop%2Ccsharp
- https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-type-ahead-search-adaptive-cards/csharp

I'm having the following Adaptive Card returned from the OnTeamsMessagingExtensionFetchTaskAsync (from message action):

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.5",
  "body": [
    {
      "id": "choiceSelect",
      "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
      "choices": [
        {
          "title": "Choice 1",
          "value": "Choice 1"
        },
        {
          "title": "Choice 2",
          "value": "Choice 2"
        }
      ],
      "placeholder": "Placeholder text",
      "style": "filtered",
      "choices.data": {
        "type": "Data.Query",
        "dataset": "cases"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Card is rendered correctly, but when I start typing, I'm getting the following results:

[image]

No request is being made. I was trying to debug the JS, but it is troublesome for me - I couldn't pinpoint the exact place it fails, but got these symbols to lookup: `executeSearchInvoke`, `enableAppPermissionEnforcement` and `enableTenantSettingsForBots` in `3.2-app.min.js`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is there some kind of dependency or permission I should add to the bot? Some setting in Teams Admin Center? I can add that static typeahead works flawlessly, but I need the dynamic one (big data collection to query).

EDIT:
I have confirmed that the app is added to the team (it is visible on the list of apps in team settings); I've removed and added it again just in case. I am still getting the same results.

List of permissions visible from the App details page:

> This app will have permission to:
>
> - Receive messages and data that I provide to it.
> - Send me messages and notifications.
> - Access my profile information such as my name, email address, company name, and preferred language.
> - Receive messages and data that team members provide to it in a channel.
> - Send messages and notifications in a channel.
> - Access this team's information such as team name, channel list and roster (including team member's names and email addresses) - and use this to contact them​.

Comment: Looks like you haven't installed the bot in that particular scope (Personal/Team) where you are trying the type-ahead on Adaptive Card. Could you please reverify once?

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft I did confirm that and updated the question. Also, I think when the application would not be installed, I won't see its contents (and I'm handling the `justInTimeInstall` request).

Comment: Could you please set up and check It once with this sample. https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-type-ahead-search-adaptive-cards/csharp

Comment: @Kamil Gierach-Pacanek - Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved or still looking for any help?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT The dynamic typeahead indeed works when I use your sample solution. The difference is that I am using Adaptive Card in the task flow scenario with messaging extension (`OnTeamsMessagingExtensionFetchTaskAsync`). Can that be an issue?

Comment: You can't get rich card experiences with dynamic search, such as query based messaging extensions.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/dynamic-search?tabs=desktop%2Ccsharp#dynamic-typeahead-search

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT sorry for the delayed response - I have this topic frozen for a while. I want to clarify that I don't want to launch adaptive card experience from the dynamic query search. What I have is a messaging extension that shows a form which I control using `OnTeamsMessagingExtension[FetchTask/SubmitAction]Async`. On such form I'd like to have dynamic search control. This supports how I formulated the question.

Comment: Please refer the following document:-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/msgext-message-reminder/csharp/MessagingExtensionReminder/Bots/ActivityBot.cs#L46

Comment: Excuse me, @Sayali-MSFT, can you elaborate on how it is relevant to dynamic search queries? I have troubles figuring it out.

Comment: If I am correct, as you mention above you don't want to launch adaptive card,you want messaging extension that shows a form. as you see here, In that sample they are using the form for messaging extention.https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/msgext-message-reminder/csharp

Comment: You need to call  this section:-   protected override async Task<MessagingExtensionActionResponse> OnTeamsMessagingExtensionFetchTaskAsync(
            ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext,
            MessagingExtensionAction action,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: @KamilGierach-Pacanek Hi, could you please enlighten me regarding the dataset: "cases"? I've seen a similar definition but I can't figure out what "cases" refers to. Appreciate it!